If $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive reals, prove that $\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(c+a)^2} \ge \frac{3}{4}$.

If $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive reals, prove that $\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(c+a)^2} \ge \frac{3}{4}$.

(I would appreciate more without expanding the LHS or atleast keeping the calculative complexity least).
My approach:
By Titu's Lemma:
$$\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(c+a)^2} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b)^2 + (b+c)^2 + (c+a)^2} = \frac{\sum{a^2}+2\sum{ab}}{2\sum{a^2}+2\sum{ab}} \cdots(1)$$
By A.M.-G.M. $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \ge ab \implies \sum{a^2} \ge \sum{ab} \cdots(2)$
Using (2) in (1) :
$$\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(c+a)^2} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b)^2 + (b+c)^2 + (c+a)^2} = \frac{\sum{a^2}+2\sum{ab}}{2\sum{a^2}+2\sum{ab}} \ge \frac{3\sum{ab}}{4\sum{a^2}}$$
How to proceed from here ?

I started with Titu's lemma but it didn't help much

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3733508/42969

Thanks to remind i already saw that one but maybe didn't look at the second approach which seems interesting

(To be explicit, nguyenhuyenag's solution in Martin's link has a solution to your problem.)

@CalvinLin yeah I already saw his nguyenhuenag's solution a while ago but my question is why I can't proceed further with Titu's lemma ? (am I doing something wrong ?)

It's "wrong" because the bound is too loose (EG No longer true for $(1, \approx 0, \approx 0)$. You need to "weight" the values further, which is what treating $a^2/(a+b)^2$ as $a^2(a+c)^2 / ([a+b)^2(a+c)^2]$ does. $\quad$ I haven't developed a strong intuition for what weights work, and mostly do a trial and error to adjust the values. $\quad$ My first 2 attempts would have been $a^2 a^2/[(a+b)^2a^2]$ and $a^2(a+b)^2 / [(a+b)^2(a+b)^2]$, and you can verify that they don't work either.  Note that $ a^2(a+2c)^2/ [(a+b)^2(a+2c)^2]$ does work.

(Very rough heuristics) In your case, 4 X numerator - 3 X denominator is $ \sum - 2a^2 + 2ab$ hence will not work. We can increase the $a^2$ part by multiplying by $a^2 / a^2$$\quad$ Then, for each of my trial and error approaches, if you expand out 4 X numerator - 3 X denominator, you can see that the cross term $a^3b$ has a large negative sign, and so we need to tweak the weights to increase $a^3b$, which is why $(a+c)^2/(a+c)^2$ is more likely to work that $(a+b)^2/(a+b)^2$. Also, had that not worked, I would have tried $(a+2c)^2  / (a+2c)^2$ to further increase the $a^3b $ term.

@CalvinLin sorry but I m still not getting what do u exactly mean by bound is too loose
